# Should an R Package be able to output to user's hard drive?

Tags: r, file-io, package

I'm developing an R package for conservation scientists to run Bayesian data analyses on animal survey data. One of the features I want to implement is a final "analysis report" in the form of an RMarkdown file.

What are the best practices for R package development when it comes to saving R data to user's hard drive? For example, if I had an exported function called `create_analysis(...)`, is it "okay" to allow to user to enter, as a function argument, an output directory for the function to save the RMarkdown file to? Or, should this function just return an R object with this RMarkdown file contained in it, and the user has to save it themselves?

EDIT: I should add that I am asking this question because I haven't come across anything in, say, Hadley Wickham's R Package book regarding outputting, nor have I seen it anywhere else. My thought is essentially, if the R package is allowed to output to the user's hard drive, does that place the onus of blame on me, the package developer, if something goes wrong in writing to file (i.e. overwrites something important on the user's computer), or does the user accept responsibility because they are the ones that specify output directory?

Comment: It's fine to have such a function, but you might want to make it a little more clear by including the word "save" or "write" in the function name as in e.g. `write.csv` or `ggsave`

Comment: @Ryan Thank you for your suggestion! I didn't actually realize ggplot had a `ggsave` function. This confirms to me that it is okay for an external R package to output files, but I will be sure to make it explicitly clear in the function name that that's what it will be doing.

Comment: One other thing:  your function's help page should have examples, and they should definitely not write to the current directory.  Use `tempfile()` or `tempdir()` to get a location in the session's temporary directory, and write there.  And it's often best to call `unlink()` at the end of the example to clean up, especially if you are using a lot of disk space.